# Csv data file to string data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv

Is it possible to convert csv data with this format:

```
    date,value1,value2,value3//CSV header
    2015-11-04,58,221,12//second row csv
    2015-11-05,62,234,18
    2015-11-06,69,258,22
...
```

to this format?

```
[12,18,22,...]//Get the data from value3 field
```

The web references I have seen converts csv file to array, but not into the same format i have written above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it in two steps; 1. importing the CSV (framework), 2. selecting the column you want (regular multidimensional arrays).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am new into programming so first i will search your option and then i will apply step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rows = data.split("\n");
var array = [];
var final = [];

$.get("csvstring.php", function(data) {
    $.each(rows, function(index, value){
        if(index > 0) {
            var values = value.split(",");
            array.push(values);
        }
    });

    $.each(array, function(index, value){
        $.each(value, function(indexs, values) {
          console.log(index);
          if(indexs == 3) {
            final.push(values);
          }
        });
    });
});

console.log(final);
```

This returns:

```
["12", "18", "22"]
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: And if the csv data were a file with unlimited rows(data.csv)?,first i must to parse it?.

Comment: What do you mean? This will do with any amount of rows!

Comment: When i put a csv file: ` var CSV =    "data.csv"` instead data like the example ` var CSV =    "2015-11-04,58,221,12\n2015-11-05,62,234,18\n2015-11-06,69,258,22"` i get in console:
0   csvstring.php:26 //and
[]    csvstring.php:33 
the csv file is the same like question

Comment: Then combining both methods.Thanks.

Comment: Works great. The final step to get the object is remove the first element,in this case "value3":["value3","12","18","22",...] to ["12","18","22",...].

Answer (score 0):

You can load it by using $.get and parse it using .split(), here's a little example.

```
$.get("YOUR.csv", function(data){
  var yourParsedCSV = data.split("\n").map(function(i){return i.split(",")});
});
```

Heres what it does, explained

1º split rows with

```
data.split("\n");
```

2º loop rows and return them as arrays splitting by commas ( .map is the fastest option)

```
...map(function(i){ //for every item in the previous array...
  return i.split(","); //return it as array
});
```